# Session authentication for both browser and non-browser clients

Tags: http, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

I would like to know if the following design for token-based authentication is sound.

1. Client posts login credential
2. After validating, server generates `(session_key, expires_at) <- (a 256-bit pseudo-random string, some date in the future)` and save it in the storage system of choice.
3. Server sets the session_key in the HTTP-Only cookie in the response.
4. Server sets the response payload `{session_key: ..., expires_at: ...}`. The reason is that non-browser clients do not have cookie and they will read this payload, locally store it for the future use.

Concretely, I think the system needs to send the token in the payload as well as a cookie for non-browser clients. Is this a common practice? Or am I missing something important, and there are better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525490/sending-seesion-key-in-the-header-vs-http-only-cookie), this is fine. It doesn't expose the session key any more than if it is only in a cookie. This could only happen if the attacker can call your authentication endpoint with a valid user/password combo.

Make sure your **authentication endpoint does not accept valid sessions and echo back their key** as that could expose you to CSRF and session stealing!

For alternative authentication methods, check out the [Web Authentication Guide](https://www.securitydrops.com/the-web-api-authentication-guide/), I put together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate more on why a system should not "accept valid sessions and echo back their key"?

Comment: The session ID is protected by an HTTPOnly cookie. It is not possible for any script on the page to extract it from the browser. If however, your login endpoint (referred to as authentication endpoint above) accepts valid sessions and echoes back the session ID, it can be leaked to scripts. Another scenario is if you have CORS, then an attacker can issue a Cross-Origin request to the login endpoint and obtain the session ID.